# ReplyError: MOVED 10784 10.64.128.43:7001 on Nestjs using BulMQ with Redis

Tags: kubernetes, redis, nestjs, bullmq

We're trying to set up Redis for use with BullMQ with our NestJs app in K8s.   We're getting a MOVED error when we deploy to Kubernetes.  We're not sure if we setup the YAML correctly, as we copied from an existing app.  We were given a HOST as well and its port 7001.

```
ReplyError: MOVED 10784 10.**.***.**:7001
    at parseError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
    at parseType (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14)
```

our QueueModule

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { REDIS_QUEUES } from '../../constants';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
    imports: [
        // initialize BullModule with redis connection
        BullModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                redis: {
                    host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
                    port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT')
                }
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService]
        })
    ],
    exports: [BullModule]
})
export class QueueModule {}
```

our redis-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
  namespace: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 7001
      targetPort: 7001
      name: redis-cluster
  clusterIP: __REDIS_HOST__
  selector:
    app: redis
```

and our Redis Feature

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: redis
    env: __NAME__
    name: redis
  name: redis
  namespace: __PROJECT__
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  strategy:
    recreateParams:
      timeoutSeconds: 600
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
        name: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: __REGISTRY__/redis:5.0.5-alpine
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7001
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            tcpSocket:
              port: 7001
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            tcpSocket:
              port: 7001
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 5Gi
          securityContext:
            capabilities: {}
            privileged: false
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data
              name: redis-data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
        - emptyDir: {}
          name: redis-data
```

TIA for any insight that can be provided.